# drawing a shapes of camera using openGL in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, camera, windows-7-x64

using 6 parameters : (x,y,z) for position and (AngleToX,AngleToY,AngleToZ) the angles of shape around axis, I want to draw a camera in 3d screen; I want to clear that it is a camera;

Can you explain How can I draw a shape such as a camera and if you have any samples that help to understand give me;

Comment: The "Hello World" of OpenGL is a spinning cube.  If you can do that, you're on your way.  Anything else, like loading and displaying a camera model, requires libraries and some knowledge of how to handle the data and structures such libraries instantiate.  There are tutorials all over the net, by the way (for spinning cube).

Comment: yeah but which library do you suggest?

Comment: I've used AssImp in the past.  It's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

We can draw a polygon using many number of triangles. For example square need two triangles, cube need 12 triangles.But a shape like camera are complex polygon we can't calculate the total number of triangle faces of camera by ourselves. For that we have to use 3D model to draw complex shape like camera. I suggest you to use Blender it is open source also. With the help of blender model the 3D camera and export it in .obj format or other. Write .obj parser to load obj model and render it using OpenGL.
Here is the sample tutorial http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/07/modern-opengl3d-model-obj-loaderparser.html

You can also download the free 3d model through Google and many library are their to load the 3D model of different format.

If your are new to OpenGL then it will be difficult for you. So at first understand opengl in depth.

Comment: thank you so much! yeah ! I drew it by triangles;) but it is not good enough! I have used SOIL library before;) but it is a little complex;) because I want to draw a lot of object and when I used SOIL to load picture, they have conflict and it is not good!

Comment: If you have problem with SOIL ask another question. This thread may help you for choosing libary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776408/whats-a-good-c-library-for-loading-models-for-use-in-opengl

Comment: and another question : Is Blender an IDE or a library?

Comment: Blender(http://www.blender.org/) is opensource 3D modeling software to create model it is not libary.